# Taking advantage of both async and multithreading to make rapid code in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I want to create a program that can ping (icmp), scan ports, get HTTP for each host with custom timeout. Program needs to utilize maximum CPU as possible to make it efficient. Using async in main thread is good at first glance but actually doesn't corresponds with high load requirements. I expect to scan 100,000 hosts in less than 60 seconds with 0.0005 ratio (0.05%) of hosts that are DOWN (waiting for the timeout).

I'm wondering how to create many threads and run asynchronous scanning of a batch of hosts in them. Open to any kind of other solutions to this kind of problem.

```py
async def ping_host(host, timeout=5, retry=1):
    for i in range(retry):
        try:
            delay = await aioping.ping(host, timeout=timeout)
            return True, host, delay
        except (OSError, asyncio.TimeoutError, socket.gaierror):
            pass
    return False, host


def ping_hosts(hosts):
    results = {}
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = []
        for host in hosts:
            task = loop.run_in_executor(pool, ping_host, host)
            tasks.append(task)
        for index, task in enumerate(asyncio.as_completed(tasks)):
            host = hosts[index]
            try:
                result = loop.run_until_complete(task)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Ex: {e}")
                result = False
            results[host] = result
    return results
```

```
Ex: This event loop is already running
...
google.com: DOWN
False (RESULT)
...
```

Comment: Why are you constraining the number of threads?

Comment: To the number of CPU threads? Usually adding much higher above it's value won't increase the performance.

Comment: I heard many times that multithreading can be useful for CPU-bound tasks but asynchronous is often a better choice for I/O bound tasks in terms of efficiency

Comment: That may be the case for multiprocessing but not multithreading. Note that since 3.8 the default for max_workers is *min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)* Therefore, even if you did not specify your own constraint there would be more threads available. Bear in mind that your main functionality is I/O (network) bound and therefore well-suited to multithreading. Maybe just try without any constraint and measure the results. Personally, I wouldn't be mixing asyncio with multithreading unless I'd already proven that multithreading in its simpler form is not performing as well as I'd hope

Comment: Oh. I messed up with the code because I wanted to use both worlds of async and threading so I get Exception in the output and always get False result probably because async function is not awaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using Queues for this task. I just tested and it can ping 100 hosts using around 2 seconds. The Queue is set to can hold 50 jobs maximum, but as soon as a job completes a new is added, so it'll be very fast. You could set it 100 without issues. It should be able to handle many thousands of hosts in no time.

Code:

```
from asyncio import run, Queue, create_task
from aioping import ping
from time import perf_counter

async def ping_host(host, taskQueue, resultsQueue, timeout, retry):
    try:
        delay = await ping(host, timeout)
        await resultsQueue.put([True, host, delay])
    except TimeoutError:
        if retry:
            try:
                delay = await ping(host, timeout)
                await resultsQueue.put([True, host, delay])
            except: await resultsQueue.put([False, host, f"{host} timed out (retried)."])
        else: await resultsQueue.put([False, host, f"{host} timed out."])
    taskQueue.task_done()
    taskQueue.get_nowait()

async def ping_hosts(hosts, timeout=2, retry=False):
    # hosts = [["host1.com"], ["host2.com"], [...]]
    results: list = []
    taskQueue: Queue = Queue(maxsize=50)
    resultsQueue: Queue = Queue()
    for host in hosts:
        await taskQueue.put(create_task(ping_host(host[0], taskQueue, resultsQueue, timeout, retry)))
    await taskQueue.join()
    while not resultsQueue.empty():
        results.append(await resultsQueue.get())
        resultsQueue.task_done()
    await resultsQueue.join()
    return(results)

async def main():
    script_start: float = perf_counter()
    hosts: list = [["1.1.1.1"], ["81.83.12.253"], ["46.246.29.69"],["77.68.88.76"],["195.238.40.45"],["8.8.8.8"], ["1.0.0.1"], ["198.101.242.72"], ["23.253.163.53"], ["205.204.88.60"], ["91.239.100.100"], ["89.233.43.71"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"], ["test.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"], ["test.com"], ["1.1.1.1"], ["81.83.12.253"], ["46.246.29.69"],["77.68.88.76"],["195.238.40.45"],["8.8.8.8"], ["1.0.0.1"], ["198.101.242.72"], ["23.253.163.53"], ["205.204.88.60"], ["91.239.100.100"], ["89.233.43.71"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"], ["test.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"],["google.com"], ["bing.com"], ["yahoo.com"], ["test.com"]]
    test: list = await ping_hosts(hosts)
    print(test)
    print(f"Script has finished. It took {round(perf_counter()-script_start, 2)} seconds to run.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Testing 64 hosts, results:

```
[[True, '1.1.1.1', 0.009948200000000018], [True, '46.246.29.69', 0.0228458], [True, 'bing.com', 0.015366999999999992], [True, '1.0.0.1', 0.013153100000000001], [True, 'bing.com', 0.020199400000000006], [True, '89.233.43.71', 0.02210000000000001], [True, 'bing.com', 0.019370899999999996], [True, '77.68.88.76', 0.035211400000000004], [True, 'bing.com', 0.018472500000000003], [True, '81.83.12.253', 0.03657640000000001], [True, '91.239.100.100', 0.023512000000000005], [True, 'bing.com', 0.01855379999999998], [True, '8.8.8.8', 0.028554300000000005], [True, 'google.com', 0.0303359], [True, 'bing.com', 0.015900700000000018], [True, 'google.com', 0.026591299999999984], [True, '1.1.1.1', 0.017966500000000024], [True, '1.0.0.1', 0.018603599999999998], [True, 'google.com', 0.028806400000000038], [True, '91.239.100.100', 0.0188546], [True, 'bing.com', 0.017099299999999984], [True, 'google.com', 0.028467900000000018], [True, '195.238.40.45', 0.03879199999999999], [True, 'google.com', 0.027985999999999983], [True, '89.233.43.71', 0.021615100000000026], [True, 'bing.com', 0.021515199999999984], [True, '46.246.29.69', 0.027923399999999987], [True, '8.8.8.8', 0.02808860000000002], [True, 'google.com', 0.03274550000000001], [True, 'google.com', 0.027735399999999966], [True, 'bing.com', 0.021062299999999978], [True, 'google.com', 0.026245300000000027], [True, 'google.com', 0.027394100000000005], [True, 'google.com', 0.024639000000000022], [True, 'bing.com', 0.011746499999999993], [True, 'bing.com', 0.011770199999999953], [True, 'bing.com', 0.01149420000000001], [True, '81.83.12.253', 0.03624450000000001], [True, '195.238.40.45', 0.03807920000000001], [True, '77.68.88.76', 0.040769900000000026], [True, 'google.com', 0.02052520000000002], [True, 'google.com', 0.021225800000000017], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.12673379999999998], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.13697290000000004], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.1341727], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.1289647], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.11841639999999998], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.12921200000000005], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.17543620000000001], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.17722649999999998], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.17867729999999998], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.18185169999999998], [True, 'yahoo.com', 0.1791689], [True, 'yahoo.com', 
0.17632149999999996], [False, '23.253.163.53', '23.253.163.53 timed out.'], [False, '205.204.88.60', '205.204.88.60 timed out.'], [False, 'test.com', 'test.com timed out.'], [False, '198.101.242.72', '198.101.242.72 timed out.'], [False, 'test.com', 'test.com timed out.'], [False, '205.204.88.60', '205.204.88.60 timed out.'], [False, 'test.com', 'test.com timed out.'], [False, '23.253.163.53', '23.253.163.53 timed out.'], [False, '198.101.242.72', '198.101.242.72 timed out.'], [False, 'test.com', 'test.com timed out.']]
Script has finished. It took 2.09 seconds to run.
```

Comment: 50 queue size performed 56 seconds for 100k hosts in my benchmark. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for you solution. By the way, when I desreased the queue size (16) I started to get "Task exception was never retrieved
ValueError: task_done() called too many times at main.py:19" even for a small amount of hosts (100). Program doesn't terminate on it but it doesn't output anything besides the expection itself.

Comment: @Cranwell Weird, If I try the same I get no error. I'm on Python 3.9.13.

Comment: What version of asyncio do you have installed?

Comment: Queue.task_done() Raises a ValueError if called more times than there were items placed in the queue. It's the matter of threading issues, I think.